# Como mudar a fonte padrão dos componentes Swing?

Tags: java, swing, font

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu mudar o padrão das fontes de *labels* e botões do Swing, se possível, do projeto geral.

Todos os *labels* que eu crio eu tenho que ficar mudando a fonte para um que seja maior um pouco e de outro estilo, isso é cansativo e perco muito tempo.
Procurei bastante em como alterar e não achei nada.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Vc pode criar um formulário modelo e depois é só herdar as propriedades deste formulário modelo no seu formulários novos.

Comment: Por exemplo, quero colocar um padrão de Arial e 14 de tamanho com negrito. Eu gostaria que TODOS os Labels e botões que eu criasse já começassem com esse padrão, porque é foda ter que ficar mudando toda santa vez que você cria um novo label ou botão, por exemplo.

Comment: Sua pergunta dá a entender que gostaria de alterar as fontes do IDE Netbeans, não de uma aplicação Java. Se está usando o construtor de interface gráfica do Netbeans, então está trabalhando com [**Swing**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29). Editei a pergunta, você pode [**reverter**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/93061/revisions) se a edição não apresentar melhorias.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [essa resposta no jGuru](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=340519) você pode definir a fonte de cada recurso, somente dos componentes que está interessado — no caso o *label* e o *button*.

```
UIManager.put("Button.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ToggleButton.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("RadioButton.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("CheckBox.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ColorChooser.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ComboBox.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Label.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("List.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("MenuBar.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("RadioButtonMenuItem.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("CheckBoxMenuItem.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Menu.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Panel.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ScrollPane.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Viewport.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Table.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TableHeader.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TextField.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("PasswordField.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TextArea.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TextPane.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("EditorPane.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("TitledBorder.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ToolBar.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("ToolTip.font", /* font of your liking */);
UIManager.put("Tree.font", /* font of your liking */);
```

---

Ou então pode alterar o valor dos objetos em [**`UIManager.getDefault().keys()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) que forem instância de [**`FontUIResource`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/FontUIResource.html).

> **Importante:** Essa solução vai depender do *Look and feel* da sua aplicação. 
>   Se estiver usando a [Nimbus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), por exemplo, as alterações não surtiram efeito.

```
public void setDefaultFont(Font defaultFont){

   FontUIResource font = new FontUIResource(defaultFont);

   Enumeration uiManagerKeys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
   while(uiManagerKeys.hasMoreElements()){
        Object key   = uiManagerKeys.nextElement(),
               value = UIManager.get(key);

        if(null != value && value instanceof FontUIResource)
            UIManager.put(key, font);
   }
}
```

E fazer o uso assim:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25);
setDefaultFont(font);
```

Resultado no Windows 10:

<kbd>[image: resultado]</kbd>